# How to create HTML form that contains structured text

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter Bootstrap, I have a form that looks like:

```
Name         Country         Phone Number
-----------------------------------------
John         USA
Joe          Canada
```

All of these values in the table above are going to be text fields, dropdowns, etc.

Is there a way that I can create a form that is encased in divs that when submitted, all values of the table are submitted, one by one?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        Level 1 of column
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">Level 2</div>
            <div class="span6">Level 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "one by one", line per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form ...>
  <table>
    <thead><tr> <th>Name <th>Country <th>Phone number
    <tbody>
      <tr> <td>John <td>USA
      <tr> <td>Joe <td>Canada
    ...
  </table>
</form>
```

When you have a table of data, use the `table` element, not a salad of `div` elements. Just put the table inside a `form` element. All fields are submitted in the form if they are inside the `form` element, irrespectively of intervening table (or other) markup.

It is unclear how the `div` markup is meant to relate to the question, especially because the class names do not reflect meaning.

Comment: @jukka-k-korpela the classes name refer to the classes defined in twitter-bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem